# How to make new value with two criteria by using if or ifelse function in R

Tags: r, if-statement

I'm trying to use if() or ifelse() function in R in order to make new values. Here's my data as below, and my R version is R 3.4.2(x64) for Windows.

```
Name   Group
Apple  A    
Bee    A
Can    B
Dog    B
Egg    B
Can    C
Dog    C
Flow   C
```

In short, I would like to make a result as follows.

```
Name   Group   Result
Apple  A       Red
Bee    A       Yellow
Can    B       Orange
Dog    B       Orange
Egg    B       Green
Can    C       Purple
Dog    C       Gray
Flow   C       Black
```

I tried some if and ifelse functions in R to make my result.

```
df$Result <- NA
df$Result <- if(AND(Name=="Apple", Group=="A"), "Red", "Yellow")
df$Result <- if(OR(AND(Name=="Can", Group=="B")), AND(Name=="Dog", Group=="B")), "Orange", "Green")
df$Result <- ifelse(AND(Name=="Can", Group=="C"), "Purple",
                ifelse(AND(Name=="Dog", Group=="C"), "Gray",
                   ifelse(AND(Name=="Flow", Group=="C"), "Black", NA)))
```

However, similar errors were shown.

```
Error: unexpected ',' in "df$Result <- if(AND(Name=="Apple", Group=="A"),"
In addition: Warning message:
In strsplit(code, "\n", fixed = TRUE) :
  input string 1 is invalid in this locale

Error: unexpected ',' in "df$Result <- if(OR(AND(Name=="Can", Group=="B"), AND(Name=="Dog", Group=="B")),"
In addition: Warning message:
In strsplit(code, "\n", fixed = TRUE) :
  input string 1 is invalid in this locale

Error in AND(Name=="Can", Group=="C") : could not find function "AND"
In addition: Warning message:
In strsplit(code, "\n", fixed = TRUE) :
  input string 1 is invalid in this locale
```

I also used this code.

```
df$Result <- if(AND(Name=="Apple", Group=="A"), print("Red"), print("Yellow"))
```

However, it didn't work, either. Moreover, I would like to know why 'AND' function didn't work when I employed ifelse() function.

Does anyone who can help me, please? Thanks for reading my problem. and I need your help. Thank you so much.

Comment: Are you using some packages for `AND` function?  It is not a `base R` function.  I guess `Name=="Apple" & Group=="A"`

Comment: In R we use `&` instead of `AND()`.

Comment: @akrun it is from Excel :)

Comment: @akrun I looked up some R codes, and some suggestions gave 'AND' function, but it didn't work. Therefore, I changed '&' as you gave, and ifelse function works, not if function. Thanks a lot!!

Comment: @zx8754 Yes, ifelse works after I changed 'AND' into '&'. Thanks a lot!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use `case_when` from the `dplyr` package:

```
df$result <- case_when(
    df$Name=="Apple" & df$Group=="A"                  ~ "Red",
    df$Group=="A"                                     ~ "Yellow",
    (df$Name=="Can" | df$Name=="Dog") & df$Group=="B" ~ "Orange",
    df$Group=="B"                                     ~ "Green",
    df$Name=="Can" & df$Group=="C"                    ~ "Purple",
    df$Name=="Dog" & df$Group=="C"                    ~ "Gray",
    df$Name=="Flow" & df$Group=="C"                   ~ "Black",
    TRUE                                              ~ NA
)
```

It looks like you are using Excel syntax.  Fortunately R can offer a slightly cleaner looking way of doing this.

Comment: @ Tim Biegeleisen I put codes as your suggestion. However, it doesn't work. "Error: must be type character, not logical" was shown; thus, I used as.character() to 'Name' and 'Group' values before re-trying, but it doesn't work, either. What should I do? And could you tell me how to put big space between 'Name=="Apple" & Group=="A"' and '~ "Red"', please?

Comment: Your comment does not help me help you.  My code should work as far as I can tell.

Comment: @TimBiegelesien After using "NA", it works. Thank you so much!!